# Creating model dependency diagram in Pycharm IDE with google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, pycharm, app-engine-ndb

I have a working Appengine app that I have recently imported to Pycharm IDE.

I want to generate the model dependency diagrams from it. However every time I create a google app engine dependency diagram it just returns a new blank window without any entities.

Creating the python class diagram works fine.

Any thoughts on why PyCharm is not recognizing the google app engine models that I have in my application?

many thanks

EDIT:
I have also tried creating a basic new application in PyCharm, and this also does not seem to work with creating the model dependency diagram. The problem appears to be with PyCharm, Unless anyone out there has a working model dependency diagram created by PyCharm??

Comment: Which PyCharm version was that? FWIW, I can see GAE model dependency diagrams on 5.0.5 Pro/Linux.